# The symbol "~" is not showing up

Tags: symbols, text

I am trying to type the symbol "~" in normal text, but it is not showing up. Why is this?

Comment: Have you tried `\~`?

Answer (score 8):

`~` is a latex special character for a non-breaking space. `\textasciitilde` is the command to produce `~` (in the default OT1 font there is no `~` so in that case it falls back to use the tilde accent over an empty base `\~{}`) but other font encodings do have a low `~`.